# Matrix factorisation/decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Find matrices A and B such that $$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -4 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} =A \begin{bmatrix} 2& 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} B $$

I've only learnt basic matrix diagonalisation that if I'm not mistaken should only be applicable to square matrices. How do I factorise or decompose this 2x3 matrix to find A and B? I'm not sure what method I can or should use to go about this. I would really appreciate some help with this.